# superclass object or subclass object? why?

Tags: java, class, subclass, superclass

I'm a Java beginner and I can't understand when I should create an instance of the superclass or subclass. I'm studying some tutorials online and I found a few times something like the following code:

```
package test;

class ABC{
   public void myMethod(){
    System.out.println("Overridden Method");
   }
}
public class test extends ABC{

   @Override
   public void myMethod(){
    System.out.println("Overriding Method");
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
    ABC obj = new test();
    obj.myMethod();
   }
}
```

Why I should use `ABC obj = new test();` instead of `test = new test();`?
If I need a new ABC object wouldn't it make sense to just use `ABC obj = new ABC();`?

Thank you, sorry for the noobie question.

Comment: I do that all the time. `List<Foo> myList = new ArrayList<>();`. What kind of list is used does not matter for me later. If I find out that a `LinkedList` would be better, then it's easy to switch for me. I only have to change one single thing. And I can be sure that my code will still work as before, because I only use the `List` interface and nothing special that `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` might offer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an example here, say your parent class `ABC` has static method or an instance variable

```
class ABC{
int a;
static void display(){
 System.out.println("Parent ABC");
}
```

Now you have `ABC abc = new test();`. with reference `abc`, you can access `public void myMethod()` of child class `test` and static method `static void display()` of class `ABC`. Also, you can use instance variable `a` of class `ABC`with reference `abc`.
Remember **Static Method, Instance variables, Static variables** are always invoked upon the **Type of reference** (in this case type is `ABC`). Whereas, **instance methods** are always invoked upon the **type of Object** we are referencing to (in this case we are referencing to  `test` class Object).

Answer (score 0):

When a class is being extended from another, it becomes a child class of the parent(extended class).

A parent reference can hold a child while a child reference can always hold an instance of it self.

```
test t = new test();
ABC abc = new test();
```

are both valid. And for the question why, it may come in handy to overcome some situations.

Read more about the Polymorphism concept in object oriented programming.